# How do I structure data in php to get the correct json result?

Tags: php, arrays, json, d3.js

I am working in php and need to export a json document in the following format (below).

I know how to do the actual export with `file_put_contents($data_file, json_encode($json_array));` but I'm struggling with what format I need to have the $json_array in to achieve the desired results.

I need the final json file to be formatted like this:

```
{
  "2016": [
      {
        "date": "2016/01/01",
        "close": 837
      },
      {
        "date": "2016/12/01",
        "close": 769
      }
    ],
  "2015": [
      {
        "date": "2015/01/01",
        "close": 637
      },
      {
        "date": "2015/12/01",
        "close": 669
      }
    ],
  "2014": [
      {
        "date": "2014/01/01",
        "close": 537
      },
      {
        "date": "2014/12/01",
        "close": 569
      }
    ]
}
```

Is this accomplished by exporting an array with 3 keys, each containing a multidimensional array?  Or an array of objects of some type?

Maybe I'm overthinking this, but I've been working this problem all day and have not been able to get the desired results.

To me the structure looks like an array; with the (first) key of 2016 and a value of an array, but then what's inside that array?

Comment: look at `print_r( json_decode(your_example, true));`

Comment: @splash58 The OP asks how to format the PHP array before it's _encoded_, not how to decode the json.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson So: https://eval.in/896860

Comment: @splash58 - Ah, clever! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward. Just create an array in PHP with the same leves and keys:

```
$data = [
    '2016' => [
        [
            "date"  => "2016/01/01",
            "close" =>  837
        ],
        [
            "date"  => "2016/12/01",
            "close" => 769
        ],
    ],    
    '2015' => [
        [
            "date"  => "2015/01/01",
            "close" => 637
        ],
        [
            "date"  => "2015/12/01",
            "close" => 669
        ],
    ],    
    // ... and so on
];
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/cfHqs

Comment: That looks great.  The only thing I'm still a little confused on is: how would I create this while looping through an array that has the date and close prices for each month?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson because you give to OP  the solution but not a method to solve, now you will be writing the code :)

Comment: @Keith - What while loop? When? To build the array? To use encoded result? I don't see any mentions about any looping in your question?

Comment: The data is coming out of the database and I'm putting each date key -> close value into an array.  Then I need to parse that into the array in the structure you've outlined as I add the year as a key.  I guess I'm missing how to do that.

Comment: @splash58 - The OP only asks _"I'm struggling with what format I need to have the $json_array in to achieve the desired results."_.

Comment: @Keith - Don't move the goal post of the question in comments. If this answers the original question (which it does), please mark it as accepted and create a new question with _all_ the relevant info if you have other questions/issues.

Comment: that's why I say him how to get  it :)